# Running a Service on Linux Raspbian

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, processing, systemctl

I am hoping to automatically start a program at boot on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+, running Raspbian Buster. The program is in Java (Originally created with Processing, but am able to launch it with a shell script.

I was attempting to use systemctl to do this, and have created *"reader.service"*, moved it to the appropriate folder, and enabled it to start at boot. But after a restart there is no indication that the program is running. (It should open a new window to show the program running, but does nothing.)

Checking the status of the service returns

```
reader.service - Reader Service
Loaded: loaded(/etc/systemd/system/reader.service; enabled; vendor present: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-01-04 22:53:26 PST; 483ms ago
Main PID: 1039 (Reader_0_6)
Tasks: 9 (limit: 2200)
Memory: 5.5M
CGroup: /system.slice/reader.service
```

Although using terminal or double clicking the shell script itself does launch the program successfully.

And just for completeness I'll include the actual reader.service file below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Reader Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/Readerv0.6/application.linux64/Reader_0_6
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I really appreciate any response, or tips to head in the right direction, and will be happy to include anymore information!

EDIT:
Looking further as suggested I ran *sudo journalctl -f -u reader.service* to get the logs as it ran. Which returned the following.

```
systemd[1]: Started Reader Service.
Reader_0_6[19468]: Cannot run sketch without a display. Read this for possible solutions:
Reader_0_6[19468]: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Running-without-a-Display
systemd[1]: reader.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: reader.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But the link offers solutions for running headless applications, and I am interested in using the Display. I have HDMI plugged directly in so that should not be an issue. Is there a way to pass on $DISPLAY when running the command, and after modifying reader.service to instead say `After=graphical.target` it returns the same logs.

Comment: Is your program a background program? Do you have any logs for your ```Reader_0_6```? If yes, check them.

Comment: @DarkMatter The program currently does not contain logs, but I will see about adding them, to be able to investigate further. The program is not a background program, as it should actually open up in full screen in the foreground.

Comment: @DarkMatter I ended up running _"journalctl -f -u reader.service"_ to view the logs as it ran. Returning _Started Reader Service. Reader_0_6[19345]: Cannot run sketch without a display. Read this for possible solutions: (link to github) systemd[1]: reader.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE systemd[1]: reader.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'_ So it seems this is more an issue with Processing itself, which is the program I used to create the java application and export it to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A service is not bound to any graphical device by default, unfortunately.

What I ended up doing was hard to find:

```
[Service]
# ... other options ...
# Necessary:
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
# Bonus no black screen:
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/xset -dpms
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/xset s off
# Bonus stdout on Ctrl+Alt+F8:
StandardOutput=append:/dev/tty8
```

Unfortunately Chromium now crashes with this setup, so something has changed. I do not know if your program will be affected though.